# Yii: different page regions

Tags: php, layout, yii

i have a yii site that contains main layout. in this main layout file i have a piece of code that prints the current page's output. here it is:

```
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

so the question is how to make other regions on the page?
for example i want to have a banners block, that will be printed out depending on the page. is there a way to write something like

```
<?php echo $banners; ?>
```

inside the main layout and this region will be filled with some data returned from a controller?

thanks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example

add main layout:

```
<?php $this->renderPartial('/site/_banners'); ?>
```

create view file (protected/views/site/_banners.php):

```
write banners code...
```